# Collection View cells with full-width and dynamic height

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to create a feed of posts, like you'd see in the Twitter or Facebook app. From my understanding, I should be using a `Collection View`, so I've set one up.

But now, I'm confused as to how to make the cells full-width and the height of the cells dynamic, since the text within the cell can vary from just 1 line to many dozens of lines.

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: IF you want your cells to be the width of the screen, you should be looking at a `UITableView` rather than a `UICollectionView`

Comment: @AshleyMills From what I've read though, `UICollectionView` has many advantages over `UITableView`, like animations. Is this true?

Answer (score 0):

You may need `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` instance

```
let frame: CGRect = ...
let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
layout.estimatedItemSize = CGSize.zero
self.collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: someFrame, collectionViewLayout: layout)
```

About `estimatedItemSize`:

> The default value of this property is CGSizeZero. Setting it to any other value causes the collection view to query each cell for its actual size using the cell’s preferredLayoutAttributesFitting(_:) method. If all of your cells are the same height, use the itemSize property, instead of this property, to specify the cell size instead.

Then you may design your UICollectionViewCell and in `awakeFromNib()` add an internal constraint to set exact width.

Then in `cell for item at index path` method you may do next:

```
let cell = ... as? MyCustomCell
cell?.load(model: someModel, widthConstraint: collectionView.bounds.width)
```

Important thing is to handle view size changes on rotation and split screen modes:

```
override func viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
    super.viewWillTransition(to: size, with: coordinator)
    coordinator.animate(alongsideTransition: { _ in
        self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout.invalidateLayout()
    }) { _ in }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First that you would need is a `UITextView.`
Make sure it's scroll is disabled and you set the text content accordingly. For this open the Interface Builder, select the text view and there will be a section called "Scroll View". Uncheck Scrolling Enabled. This is very important so that UITextView skips the scrolling and stretches the content as much as required.

**ViewController:**

Secondly, in your ViewController you need to handle SubView Layout changes. This is called when rotation's are made or any size of the ViewController's view changes.

```
 override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
        if let layout  = self.collection.collectionViewLayout as? UICollectionViewFlowLayout {
            layout.estimatedItemSize = CGSize(width: self.collection.frame.size.width-layout.sectionInset.left-layout.sectionInset.right-self.collection.contentInset.left - self.collection.contentInset.right, height: 100.0)

        }
    }
```

**UICollectionViewCell Subclass:**

Once you set the esitmatedItemSize, it's time to provider preferredLayoutAttributesFitting. You will have to override the UICollectionViewCell subclass.

```
override func preferredLayoutAttributesFitting(_ layoutAttributes: UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes) -> UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes {

        layoutAttributes.size =   self.getCellHeight()

        return layoutAttributes
    }

    func getCellHeight()->CGSize{

        self.setNeedsDisplay()
        self.layoutIfNeeded()

        let size = self.contentView.systemLayoutSizeFitting(UILayoutFittingExpandedSize)
        return size
    }
```